# Elastic search sort with match word if it is exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document structure example:

```
{
        'is_creator' : 1,
        'is_verified_by_id' : 0,
        'is_verified' : 0,
        'country' : 'US'
}
```

currently i do have the following sorting filter

```
        ["is_creator" => "desc"],
        ["is_verified" => "desc"]
```

so it will sort the creator users first then the verified ones and etc..

**Question:**

How i can search the results with same sorting method but for selected country first then other countries, for example i want to apply the same sort but the country must be US then other countries, like this order:

```
- Creators from the same country (US).

- Creators from rest countries (other countries).

- Verified by Admin from same country (US)

- Verified by Admin rest countries (other countries).

- Verified by ID from same country (US)

- Verified by ID from rest countries (other countries)

- Not verified from same country (US)

- Not verified from rest countries (other countries)
```

i hope the question is understandable.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### In elastic search you can use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to in combination with term query to search.

Below are the queries you asked:

###### - Creators from the same country (US).

*Use `must` block of bool query to specify that the result docs **must** meet the specified condition*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ]
   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Creators from rest countries (other countries)

*Use `must_not` block of bool query to specify that the result docs **must not** meet the specified condition*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must_not": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ]
   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Verified by Admin from same country (US)

*Add one more term for admin verification in `must` block*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } },
       { "term": { "is_verified": { "value": 1 } } }
     ]
   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Verified by Admin rest countries (other countries).

*Add `is_verified` to `must` block and `country` to `must_not` to get the only the verified docs for all countries other than the specified country*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "is_verified": { "value": 1 } } }
     ],
     "must_not": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ]

   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Verified by ID from same country (US)

*Add `is_verified_by_id` and `country` to the `must` block to get the only the verified by id docs for the specified country*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } },
       { "term": { "is_verified_by_id": { "value": 1 } } }
     ]
   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Verified by ID from rest countries (other countries)

*Add `is_verified_by_id` to `must` block and `country` to `must_not` to get the only the verified by id docs for all countries other than the specified country*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "is_verified_by_id": { "value": 1 } } }
     ],
     "must_not": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ]

   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Not verified from same country (US)

*Add `is_verified` to `must_not` block and `country` to `must` to get the non verified docs for the specified country*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ],
     "must_not": [
       { "term": { "is_verified": { "value": 1 } } }
     ]

   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

###### - Not verified from rest countries (other countries)

*Add `is_verified` and `country` to `must_not` block to get the non verified docs for the countries other than the specified one*

```
GET <INDEX_NAME>/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must_not": [
       { "term": { "is_verified": { "value": 1 } } },
       { "term": { "country": { "value": "US" } } }
     ]

   } 
  },
  "sort": [
    { "is_creator": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "is_verified": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```